# Which Symfony environment variable is available in which file (.env, .env.local, etc.)?

Tags: php, symfony, environment-variables

I have just started a new Symfony 5 project (only worked on Symfony 3 before) and I am having a hard time to understand how values in `.env` and `.env.local` work together.

The Symfony docs say, that values in `.env.local` will override values from `.env`:

> If you need to override an environment value (e.g. to a different
> value on your local machine), you can do that in a .env.local file:

All machines I am working on use the same basic setup (same DB server, etc.) but some values are different (DB name, password, etc.). Thus I wanted to put the common configuration in `.env` and the device specific values in `.env.local`:

```
# .env
...
DB_SERVER="localhost"
DB_VERSION="10.4"

DB_USER=${DB_DBNAME}

DATABASE_URL="mysql://${DB_USER}:${DB_PASS}@${DB_SERVER}/${DB_DBNAME}?serverVersion=${DB_VERSION}"
```

```
# .env.local
DB_DBNAME="someDB"
DB_PASS="secretPW"
```

When using this setup I get an error and `php bin/console debug:container --env-vars` shows `DATABASE_URL "mysql://:@localhost/?serverVersion=10.4"`. Obviously `DATABASE_URL` is build ignoring the values from `.env.local`.

I can easily solve this by moving `DATABASE_URL="mysql://...` to `.env.local` but is this the intended way of using `.env` and `.env.local`?

I thought values of these files are merged where `.env.local` values override `.env` values. Is this not the case? Or did I make some error?

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes, using `SOME_VAR=${OTHER_VAR}...` is no problem and is explicitly mentioned in the Symfony docs. It just seems that only vars from the same file are available and I would like to know if this correct/intended or if there is something wrong with my config.

Comment: While it is true that .env is loaded followed by .env.local, I like to think of .env as a template file and I just completely copy it into .env.local and then set my local values in .env.local.  It is easier for me to just have one file for configuration instead of trying to split stuff up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which Symfony environment variable is available in which file (.env, .env.local, etc.)?

`.env` is loaded before `.env.local`, and **each file is processed independently of each other**.

For interpolation purposes, only the environment variables defined in the same file, **or in in a file processed earlier**, are available during `.env` file processing.

While environment variables defined in more specific `env` files do trump those defined in more general ones, in your example when `DB_DBNAME` and `DB_PASS` are overwritten/defined too late to be of use, since `DATABASE_URL` (which depends on those) is defined earlier and not redefined in the `.env.local` file .

---

But, you can accomplish what you want to do, you just have to do it a different way.

First, create your `DATABASE_URL` environment variable with **parameter placeholders**, like this:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://%DB_USER%:%DB_PASS%@%DB_SERVER%/%DB_DBNAME%?serverVersion=%DB_VERSION%"
```

Then, in your `services.yaml` file, define the container parameters for all these values:

```yaml
# services.yaml
parameters:
    DB_DBNAME: "%env(DB_DBNAME)%"
    DB_USER: "%env(DB_USER)%"
    DB_PASS: "%env(DB_PASS)%"
    DB_SERVER: "%env(DB_SERVER)%"
    DB_VERSION: "%env(DB_VERSION)%"
    
# rest of your services.yaml file follows
```

It's important that your doctrine configuration reads like this (which is the default), including the `resolve` bit:

```yaml
# doctrine.yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
```

With this you'd get your desired results.

Answer (score 1):

I think the order is relevant in this case: as you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/symfony/dotenv/blob/5.3/Dotenv.php#L109), `.env` is fully loaded and only afterwards `.env.local` is read. That means setting the variables from `.env.local` to a variable from `.env` looks impossible, while it would work the other way around.

The [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#env-file-syntax) also mentions this pitfall, along with an example:

> The order is important when some env var depends on the value of other env vars.